# How to copy multiple tables (with same columns names) to a new table <SQL>.?

Tags: mysql, copy

How to copy multiple tables (with same columns names) to a new table `<SQL>`?

Like:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
   p1 longtext,
   p2 longtext,
   op1 varchar
   op2 varchar,
);


CREATE TABLE t2
(
   p1 longtext,
   p2 longtext,
   op1 varchar
   op2 varchar,
);

CREATE TABLE t3
(
   p1 longtext,
   p2 longtext,
   op1 varchar
   op2 varchar,
);
```

What I am hoping to achieve is trying to copy all the above table t1,t2,t3 into a new table new_table.
Something like : (sql is wrong)

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS (SELECT p1,p2,op1,op2)
      FROM t1,t2,t3);
```

Also, if I get the new table created, I am expecting every time when the tables t1,t2,t3 is updated simultaneity the new_table also gets updated. - Do i need to use a trigger for this?

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you want to use `VIEW`

```
CREATE VIEW new_Table
AS
SELECT  p1, p2, op1, op2 FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT  p1, p2, op1, op2 FROM t2
UNION ALL
SELECT  p1, p2, op1, op2 FROM t3;
```

if either of the tables are updated, it automatically reflects on the view.

- [VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html)

Answer (score 0):

In case you really want to create a table, then the syntax is specific to the RDBMS.

MSSQL for example uses the syntax

```
SELECT  p1, p2, op1, op2 into MyNewTable FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT  p1, p2, op1, op2 FROM t2
UNION ALL
SELECT  p1, p2, op1, op2 FROM t3;
```

This creates a table and then fills it. To insert data into an existing table, MSSQL uses the syntax

```
INSERT INTO MyNewTable
  SELECT  p1, p2, op1, op2 FROM t1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  p1, p2, op1, op2 FROM t2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  p1, p2, op1, op2 FROM t3
```

This also differs depending on the RDBMS you use

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query :

```
INSERT INTO dbo.NewTable (Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5)
  SELECT * FROM table1
 UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM table2
 UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM table3
UNION ALL
  Select * from table4
 UNION ALL
  Select * from table5
```